# Django - Is there an easier way to to display movie genre pages using DRY

Tags: python, django

Ive created a movie website using Django 2.1, i have a few pages for genres Admin-top,Latest,Thriller,Horror,Action etc... which is fine, but i have another 10+ genres and 10+ years to do and am thinking there must be a better way, the DRY way, then to have the individual pages when the page layout is the same etc, its just the content which changes like in my detail view.. i have google,searched etc i cant seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated

Here is my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Movie, Banner
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView



# Base page for pages.
def base(request):
    return render(request, 'movies/base.html')



# HOME-PAGE
class HomeListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'movies/home.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['admin_movies'] = Movie.objects.filter(admin_top__contains='Yes').order_by('-date_posted')
        context['latest_movies'] = Movie.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
        context['thriller_movies'] = Movie.objects.filter(genre__contains='Thriller').order_by('-date_posted')
        context['horror_movies'] = Movie.objects.filter(genre__contains='Horror').order_by('-date_posted')
        context['action_movies'] = Movie.objects.filter(genre__contains='Action').order_by('-date_posted')
        # Add any other variables to the context here
        return context



# MOVIE DETAIL PAGE
class MovieDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Movie
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    template_name = 'movies/movie-detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        title_ = self.kwargs.get('title')
        return get_object_or_404(Movie, title=title_)



# ADMIN MOVIE-PAGE
class AdminListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    queryset = Movie.objects.filter(admin_top__contains='Yes')
    template_name = 'movies/admin-top.html' 
    context_object_name = 'admin_movies'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 2




# LATEST MOVIE-PAGE
class LatestListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'movies/latest.html' 
    context_object_name = 'latest_movies'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']



# THRILLER MOVIE-PAGE
class ThrillerListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    queryset = Movie.objects.filter(genre__contains='Thriller')
    template_name = 'movies/thriller.html' 
    context_object_name = 'thriller_movies'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']



# ACTION MOVIE-PAGE
class ActionListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    queryset = Movie.objects.filter(genre__contains='Action')
    template_name = 'movies/action.html' 
    context_object_name = 'action_movies'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']



# HORROR MOVIE-PAGE
class HorrorListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    queryset = Movie.objects.filter(genre__contains='Horror') # only for filter/query on field - no more at time with using this
    template_name = 'movies/horror.html' 
    context_object_name = 'horror_movies'

    ordering = ['-date_posted','genre']
```

Here is my models

from django.db import models

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    quality = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    director = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a', null=True, blank=True)
    actors = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    imbd = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    admin_top = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    banner_gif = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a', null=True, blank=True)
    image_1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    image_2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    image_3 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    image_4 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    poster = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    trailer = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    server_1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    server_2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    server_3 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    server_4 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    server_5 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.title, self.year)


class Banner(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='N/a')
    admin_top = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s - %s' % (self.title, self.genre, self.image)
```

and here is my urls

```
from django.urls import path
from .models import Movie
from .views import (
    HomeListView,
    MovieDetailView,
    AdminListView,
    LatestListView,
    ThrillerListView,
    HorrorListView,
    HomeListView,
    ActionListView,
    base
    )

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeListView.as_view(), name='movie-home'),
    path('movie-detail/<title>/', MovieDetailView.as_view(), name='movie-detail'),
    path('admin-top/', AdminListView.as_view(), name='movie-admin'),
    path('latest/', LatestListView.as_view(), name='movie-latest'),
    path('thriller/', ThrillerListView.as_view(), name='movie-thriller'),
    path('horror/', HorrorListView.as_view(), name='movie-horror'),
    path('action/', ActionListView.as_view(), name='movie-action'),
    path('base/', base, name='movie-base'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for separate views at all. The URL should capture the genre keyword, then your view uses it in the get_queryset method to get the relevant movies.

```
path("<str:genre>", GenreListView ...)
```

...

```
class GenreListView(ListView):
    model = Movie

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Movie.objects.filter(genre__contains=self.kwargs["genre"])
```

Comment: This is what is was looking for/thinking thank!, tho i keep getting this error when trying to implement it 'Reverse for 'movie-detail' with keyword arguments '{'genre': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['movie\\-detail\\/(?P<title>[^/]+)\\/$']'

Comment: Yes managed to sort it out, luckily i keep 3 backups as it got a lil messy first time round, thanks :) really is DRY and so much easier. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called e.g. `GenreListView` that subclasses `ListView`. Have all the other genre pages subclass `GenreListView`. Factor out all the common logic/member variables as part of `GenreListView` instead of putting them in the classes that inherit from it. For example, all of them use `model = Movie`, so set that on `GenreListView` instead.

If you are well-acquainted with Python OOP, you can take this to a logical extreme and factor out a lot of things that may not be as immediately obvious as `model = Movie`. For example, you could create a stub method (e.g. called `get_qs_filter()`)on the superclass which returns a filter to use when forming the queryset. The stub does nothing by itself, and instead the classes which inherit from it implement the method. But the superclass can nonetheless call `get_qs_filter()`, pass it to `Movie.objects.filter`, and set it equal to a `queryset` member variable.